# How to upgrade project from .NET framework 4.8 to 4.8.1

Tags: c#, .net, upgrade, .net-4.8

I am having .NET project in 4.8 framework and want to update it to 4.8.1. I have googled but there is not any article which will help in this. Most of talking about 4.8 only. Is there any way to upgrade to 4.8.1. TIA.

Could not find any helpful article for this.

Comment: If you don't have .NET Framework 4.8.1 in your machine, [download the runtime and developer's pack](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net481), then change the target Framework from the properties of your Projects. Is that the problem? -- You didn't describe your development environment, nor what issue you actually have

Comment: There is a project upgrade tool provided by Microsoft [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.upgradeassistant] from here you can upgrade it but it sometimes doesn't gives you the flexibility of choosing all the mini versions

Comment: @Jimi I have installed 4.8.1 already but can see in  .csproj file that, project is targeting 4.8. What to write in proj file so that project will run in 4.8.1.  TIA

Comment: If you have installed the Developer Pack, you can then change the target Framework in the Project's `Properties->Application` pane

Comment: @Jimi. I changed it to 4.8.1 now. Thanks for help. I was missing developer pack and did install only runtime.